# "This is to bring in your cognizance" or "this is to bring to your cognizance" is correct or both are correct

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I came across a sentence in  an application of my friend that read as" This is  to bring in your cognizance that ..."  and so on and so forth.
i just want to know whether "This is to bring in your cognizance" or "This is to bring to your cognizance" is correct or both are correct.
I searched online but could not get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one that sounds correct to this US English speaker is "bring **to** your cognizance".  When talking about someone's awareness, thoughts, etc., we usually use **to**.

But as a matter of style, I wouldn't use the phrase at all.  "bring to your cognizance" sounds extremely old-fashioned; [people stopped talking like that about 100 years ago.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20your%20cognizance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20your%20cognizance%3B%2Cc0)  It sounds more modern and fluent to say ["bring to your **awareness**"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20your%20awareness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20your%20awareness%3B%2Cc0).